# How to change the user for locally cloned bit-bucket repository?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repository cloned on server with my username (As bit-bucket repository clone url has username prefixed e.g. https://mybitbucketusername@bitbucket.org/project/mysubproject.git).

Server code has some local configurations that are gitignored, I don't want to change that configuration. So I can not clone new repository & make configuration changes.

So I want to change user for existing server repository, without loosing local changes on server, repository transfer as described over bit-bucket website doesn't fit in my case ( https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/change-or-transfer-repository-ownership-289964397.html ).

What is that I need to do ? Or am I missing anything here ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:
git remote remove "origin_name"

and then,

git remote add "new _origin_name" https://bitbucket.org/autoseva/autoseva_api.git

Or directly change the url by:
git remote set-url "origin_name" https://yournewbitbucketusername@bitbucket.org/project/mysubproject.git

Comment: I am assuming above change will not affect my local changes done earlier but which are gitignored.